# How to show subjects name from subjects table depending on subjects codes in users table in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have students table with subject codes in the fields named like subj_one, subj_two, subj_three etc. There are another table named subjects with subject's codes and name.

### Sample Records from students table

```
ID  Name    Subj_one   Subj_two   Subj_three
1   Mohan     101         102       107
2   Sohan     245         101       147
3   Neha      101         103       247
```

### Sample Records from subjects table

```
subj_code            subj_name
  101                Hindi
  102                English
  103                Physics
  147                Chemistry
  245                Math
```

Now how to show subject name while I am showing student's data from students table?

Comment: can you add the related Models to the question?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, firstly, create **relation for each column**. (not recommended though, but, since you mentioned that you want to achieve this without changing the database)

**e.g** for *Subj_one*, in the Student::class (model)

```
public function subjectOne() {
    return this->belongsTo('App\Subject', 'Subj_one', 'subj_code'); // 'foreign_key', 'other_key'
}
```

Then, when you are querying for the students, use `with()`.

```
$students = Student::with('subjectOne', 'subjectTwo')->get();
```

Later in your blade,

```
@foreach($students as $student)
    {{ $student->Name }} with {{ $student->subjectOne->subj_name }}
@endforeach
```

Please go though [Eloquent Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships) docs.

Comment: There are about 50 subjects in subjects table and 14 subjects in each student's row like subj_one, subj_two ..... subj_14. There are thousands of students in the students table, that's why I am facing the problem.

And most importantly I have to get lots of students details to print. You can check here webs.wexperts.xyz

user: 651
pass: e54ef6

After log in you will see two buttons, check them,

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a relationship [Many To Many.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#relationships)

Students

```
ID  Name    
1   Mohan    
2   Sohan     
3   Neha
```

Subjects

```
SubjectId           SubjectName
   101                Hindi
   102                English
   103                Physics
   147                Chemistry
   245                Maths
```

student_subject

```
   Id     Student_id           Subject_id
    1       1                    101
    2       1                    102
    3       1                    103
    4       2                    147
    5       2                    245
```

Comment: This is an old database, I have to do so without changing.