# I have a data collection in lavavel with several sessions, how to show them categorized by session

Tags: laravel

Example Data in $students array

```
id  roll  session
1    123   2014
2    321   2014
3    654   2016
4    543   2017
5    276   2017
```

I want to show them as like as below in laravel blade

```
2014
123, 321

2016
654

2017
543, 276
```

Comment: What have you tried? Stackoverflow is not a code writing service; you're expected to make an attempt to solve you issue, and provide the code you've used and any specific errors you're receiving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do **group by** by session.

This is your $students array

```
$students = [
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'roll' => 123,
        'session' => 2014
    ],
    [
        'id' => 2,
        'roll' => 321,
        'session' => 2014
    ],
    [
        'id' => 3,
        'roll' => 654,
        'session' => 2016
    ],
    [
        'id' => 4,
        'roll' => 543,
        'session' => 2017
    ],
    [
        'id' => 5,
        'roll' => 276,
        'session' => 2017
    ],
];
```

In your blade, use Laravel Collection [groupBy()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-groupby)

```
@foreach(collect($students)->groupBy('session')->toArray() as $sessionName => $student)
    {{ $sessionName }}
    <br>
    {{ implode(",", collect($student)->pluck('roll')->toArray()) }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, can you please give me another solution?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60778743/how-to-show-subjects-name-from-subjects-table-depending-on-subjects-codes-in-use